# c# calling LoadLibrary from a 64-bit process to load a 64-bit library fails

Tags: c#, pinvoke, loadlibrary

I'm having a problem on a machine while attempting at loading a library with a P/Invoke call to LoadLibrary.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
```

This is my configuration. The calling assembly (**A**) is compiled in x64 and it calls another assembly (**B**) compiled as AnyCPU. From **B** I call `LoadLibrary(dll_C_Path)` to a library **C** that is 64-bit. All this works on my machine running Win10 64-bit, but it fails on another machine running Win7 64-bit with the following error (after calling `GetLastError`): *"%1 is not a valid Win32 application"*.

On **B**, before calling `LoadLibrary` I've verified that `Environment.Is64BitProcess=true`. I've opened the library **C** with DependencyWalker and it appears 64-bit. But the most strange thing to me is that on one machine works while on another not. What can be the cause?

**EDIT**

I'm passing the full absolute path to `LoadLibrary`. Here below a screenshort from Depency Walker (library **C** is aec.dll). I'm not used to it, but one thing I noticed is that the msvcr120.dll, which aec.dll depends on, has not the icon of a 64-bit. Can this give some hint?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that it's finding a 32-bit version of C with the same name?

Comment: I'm extracting lib C from resources inside a temp folder and I've already check the path.

Comment: Pretty obvious that you copied the wrong version of msvcr120.dll.  If you have VS2013 installed then there are two on your machine, one in c:\windows\system32 and another in c:\windows\syswow64.  You need the first one, the 64-bit version.  Not a typo, the 64-bit version is in system32 and the 32-bit version in syswow64.  Wow64 is the emulator in which 32-bit processes run.

Comment: @HansPassant The PC is not mine, it is from a customer. He told me to have not VS2013 installed under Programs and Features. He has only VC++ Redist. 2013 (x64). Moreover, by searching for the dll, under system32 he sees a *msvcr120.dll* and a *msvcr120_clr0400.dll*, while on syswow64, only a *msvcr120_clr0400.dll*. How can I solve the problem and in general how should I handle problems like these on user machines?

Comment: Well, not leaving it up to a customer would be a wise choice.  Test the deployment yourself first, ensure that *all* the correct dependencies are included so all the customer has to do is copy the directory.

Comment: Via the installer (Innosetup) I check and in case install VC++ Redist. 2013, I thought this was the right way. How should I do? Should I copy msvcr120.dll on my app path? I've tested the deployment my self on different machines. This is a problem that for the moment arose only on that customer machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible explanations:

1. Your code finds a 32 bit DLL, or an otherwise invalid image. We don't know whether you rely of the DLL search path or specify an absolute path.
2. Your code finds a 64 bit DLL but when it resolves its dependencies, a 32 bit or otherwise invalid module is found.

You should do some debugging to work out what is wrong. I would write a simple C++ program to load the library and avoid the extra complexity of p/invoke. I'd use Dependency Viewer in profile mode to determine which dependency is not valid.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I've added more details in my post (see EDIT). It seems to me that your case 2 might be the cause. If yes, what can I do?

Comment: Ensure that the required dependencies are correctly installed

Comment: Yes, also Hans Passant is suggesting the same thing but I'm not sure on how I should do it...Please check also comments to my question

Comment: I don't know what your dependencies are and how you wish to meet them, distribute them etc. I don't really want to go into your specifics in comments to an answer to a much more general Question.

Comment: ok, marked as reply because I was asking the cause and you got it. I've still the problem but I'll open another question for it